# Django test ImportError: No module named 'taskbuster.unittests'

Tags: python, django, testing, tdd

I have created a project according to a tutorial and when I am running the test it seems to create the test database and run the script but I get an error

```
ImportError: No module named 'taskbuster.module_name'
```

I have changed the settings in the virtualenvwrapper postactivate. Only made things worse, meaning the test didn't start at all. 
I have changed the path in the base.py settings file, but that also only made things worse.

```
├── db.sqlite3
├── functional_tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_all_users.py
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── taskbuster
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── base.py
│   │   ├── development.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── production.py
│   │   └── testing.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── unittests
    ├── admin.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       └── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── admin.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   └── models.cpython-34.pyc
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

This is the INSTALLED_APPS content of settings/base.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'unittests',
)
```

testing.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from .base import *
DEBUG = True
```

wsgi.py

```
import os    
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application    
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "taskbuster.settings")    
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "taskbuster.settings")    
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line    
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

postactivate in tb_test

```
#!/bin/bash
# This hook is sourced after this virtualenv is activated.
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="taskbuster.settings.testing"
export SECRET_KEY="" (Secretkey has a value in the actual code)
```

predeactivate in tb_test

```
#!/bin/bash
# This hook is sourced before this virtualenv is deactivated.
unset DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
unset SECRET_KEY
```

I have activated tb_test

```
$ workon tb_test
```

And then I run a python test

```
$python manage.py test
```

The tutorial is actually working with functional_tests, but since that did not work I created a Django app unittests, so that is why they are both in there.

I hope someone could help figure this out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that the guys under each directory don't know about the other directories.  Importing cannot look up in the directory hierarchy.

What you can do is teach Python where to look for libraries with

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/project
```

This is the 'low level' way, though. There should be appropriate settings that solve this.